# Python: writing files in functional programming style

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, functional-programming

How are we supposed to write files in Python while staying functionally pure? Normally I would do something like this

```
from typing import Iterable
from io import IOBase


def transform_input(input_lines: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[str]: ...


def print_pack(input_lines: Iterable[str], output: IOBase) -> None:
    for line in input_lines:
        print(line, file=output)


def main(*args, **kwargs):
    # Somehow we get a bunch iterables with strings and a list of output streams
    packs_of_input = ... # Iterable[Iterable[str]]
    output_streams = ... # Iterable[IOBase]
    packs_to_print = map(transform_input, packs_of_input)
    for pack, output_stream in zip(packs_to_print, output_streams):
        print_pack(pack, output_stream)
```

We can replace the `for`-loop with something like this

```
list(map(lambda pack_stream: print_pack(*pack_stream), zip(packs_to_print, output_streams))
```

but it would only make it look like the printing is done functionally. The problem is that `print_pack` is not a pure function, that is all its effort results in a side-effect and it returns nothing. 
How are we supposed to write files and remain functionally-pure (or almost pure)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The `for` loop is the most readable and all in all the "right" way to do it.

Comment: @tobias_k I don't think I'm going to use it in any serious project, yet I want to know how such things are done. It's always a good thing to know a completely different paradigm, even if you don't plan to use it.

Comment: I would define a `forEach` method that would contain the `for` loop, and use that. `def forEach(iterable, func): for i in iterable: func(i)` then `forEach(input_lines, lambda x: print(x, file=output))`. (anyway, functional programing is just moving the for loop somewhere else)

Comment: This? https://effect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @CongMa yes, it looks promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, in Python, you need to have an impure function *somewhere*, so there's no way to have 100% pure functions in this application. In the end you need to do some IO, and IO is impure.

However, what you can do is try to represent a particular layer of abstraction within your application as pure functions, and isolate the part that does the actual side-effects in another module. You can do this pretty easily in an ad-hoc way -- for example, by accumulating the contents of the file you want to write as a pure immutable data structure in your main code. Then your side-effecting code can be reduced in size, since all it needs to do is dump a string to a file.

We can look to Haskell for a more rigorous way to purely represent the full power of side-effecting operations with pure functions and data structures -- using the Monad abstraction. Essentially, a Monad is something that you can bind callbacks to, to create a chain of effectful computations all based on pure functions. For the IO monad, the Haskell runtime takes care of actually performing the side-effects once you return an IO value from the `main` function -- so all the code you write is technically pure functions, and the runtime takes care of the IO.

The [Effect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/effect) library (disclaimer: I wrote it) basically implements a certain flavor of Monad (or something very close to a monad) in Python. This lets you represent arbitrary IO (and other side-effects) as pure objects and functions, and put the actual performance of those effects off to the side. So your application code can be 100% pure, as long as you have a kind of library of relatively simple side-effecting functions.

So, for example, to implement a function that writes a list of lines to a file with Effects, you'd do something like this:

```
@do
def write_lines_to_file(lines, filename):
    file_handle = yield open_file(filename)
    for line in lines:
        yield write_data(file_handle, line)
    # alternatively:
    # from effect.fold import sequence; from functools import partial
    # yield sequence(map(partial(write_data, file_handle), lines))
    yield close_file(file_handle)
```

The Effect library provides this special `do` decorator that lets you use an imperative-looking syntax to describe a pure effectful operation. The above is function is equivalent to this one:

```
def write_lines_to_file(lines, filename):
    file_handle_eff = open_file(filename).on(
        lambda file_handle:
            sequence(map(partial(write_data, file_handle), lines)).on(
                lambda _: close_file(file_handle)))
```

These both assume that three functions exist: open_file, write_data, and close_file. These functions are assumed to return Effect objects that represent the intent to perform those actions. In the end, an Effect is essentially an intent (some transparent description of an action that is requested), and one or more callbacks to run when the result of that action has been completed. The interesting distinction is that write_lines_to_file does not *actually* write lines to a file; it simply returns some representation of the *intent* to write some lines to a file.

To actually perform this effect, you need to use the `sync_perform` function, like `sync_perform(dispatcher, write_lines_to_file(lines, filename))`. This is an impure function that actually runs the performers for all the effects that your pure representation of an effectful computation use.

I could go into the details of how open_file, write_data, and close_file would need to be implemented, and the details of what the "dispatcher" argument are, but really the documentation at https://effect.readthedocs.org/ is probably the right thing to reference at this point.

I also gave a talk at Strange Loop about Effect and its implementation, which you can watch on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D37dc9EoFus

It's worth noting that Effect is a pretty heavy-handed way to keep code purely functional. You can get a long way toward maintainable code by taking a "functional core/imperative shell" approach and trying your best to write most of your code as pure functions and minimizing the effectful code. But if you're interested in a more rigorous approach, I think Effect is good. My team uses it in production and it has helped out a lot, especially with its testing API.